# KeyError using .loc with a datetime index in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-loc

I don't understand why I am getting a KeyError here.  It succeeds for one day but not the other.  I have done this sort of filtering on a datetime index before and not had this issue.

```
temp
```

```html
start time CA   end time CA
0   2021-09-20 19:00:00 2021-09-20 19:30:00
1   2021-09-19 16:30:00 2021-09-19 17:00:00
2   2021-09-19 16:30:00 2021-09-19 17:00:00
3   2021-09-17 10:30:00 2021-09-17 10:45:00
4   2021-09-17 10:30:00 2021-09-17 10:45:00
5   2021-09-17 10:30:00 2021-09-17 10:45:00
6   2021-09-17 10:30:00 2021-09-17 10:45:00
7   2021-09-17 10:30:00 2021-09-17 10:45:00
8   2021-09-17 10:30:00 2021-09-17 10:45:00


temp.dtypes
```

```html
start time CA    datetime64[ns]
end time CA      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

```html
temp.set_index('start time CA', inplace=True)

temp.loc['2021-09-19']
```

```html
end time CA
start time CA   
2021-09-19 16:30:00 2021-09-19 17:00:00
2021-09-19 16:30:00 2021-09-19 17:00:00
```

temp.loc['2021-09-20']

```html
KeyError: 'the label [2021-09-20] is not in the [index]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your column/index datetime type using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to benefit from the [pandas date/time functionalities](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html):

```
temp['start time CA'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['start time CA'])
temp = temp.set_index('start time CA')
temp.loc['2021-09-19']
```

output:

```
                             end time CA
start time CA                           
2021-09-19 16:30:00  2021-09-19 17:00:00
2021-09-19 16:30:00  2021-09-19 17:00:00
```

output for `temp.loc['2021-09-20']`:

```
                             end time CA
start time CA                           
2021-09-20 19:00:00  2021-09-20 19:30:00
```

Comment: My column is datetime.  I showed the output of temp.dtypes.  The problem is the .loc is succeeding for one date and not the other.

Comment: @RuthSmith both work for me, which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Definitely an older version (0.20.3).  I'm running on a remote machine where I did not set up environment.  I will see if I can update it.